# Shorting (connecting) two pads that are on opposite sides of the PCB

Tags: pcb, soldering, surface-mount, pins, pad

I have a PCB that has two rectangular pads on either side of the PCB, exactly opposite to each other. They need to be temporarily shorted (connected) to allow setting of some parameter through software.

I have attached picture of similar PCB where they have been shorted. I know I can do it by soldering but the problem is I am working from home and soldering isn't an option.

Is there a way I can connect these two pads and short them, maybe by using some kind of jumper pin or plug?

I am totally new to PCBs with zero experience.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question (don't post in comments) and add (a) the distances from the pads to be shorted to each of the nearest board edges, (b) the height of the tallest components along those distances.

Comment: I have no idea what that gunk on the picture is supposed to be but it ain't a proper solder joint for sure. Do you have a better high res picture?

Comment: For temporary shorting two pins, a steel screwdriver should do the trick. The plastic handle means that it won't forward ESD from your fingers to the PCB.

Answer (score 9):

A crocodile clamp bridging top to bottom side electrically?

[image]

Image borrowed from https://www.aliexpress.com/item/6-Pcs-6-Colors-55mm-Crocodile-Alligator-Clip-For-4mm-Male-Banana-Plug-Connector/32871795998.html. No affiliation.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working from home, I think a paper clip could be a viable option.
Or perhaps you could jerry-rig a crocodile clip like the one suggested in the other answer, by using a small clothespin with some aluminum foil on the inside.

Comment: Aluminum has very poor conductivity. Copper paper clips should be great to use however.

Comment: @Lundin i agree, but i figured aluminum foil would be readily available in most kitchens

Comment: Aluminum has _great_ conductivity. The transparent oxide film that's always present on its surface, not so much.